# Shortest parser for a left-recursive grammar

Tags: code-golf, parsing

Write the shortest parser for the grammar:

```
M -> M + n | n
```

- Output must be some representation of a structured value representing the concrete syntax tree produced by the input `n+n+n`.
- The code to produce the textual output from the structured value is not necessary.
- The code to read/validate input is not necessary.
- Solution is anything that can somehow be called; a function, an object, doesn't matter.
- How your solution receives input (currying character-by-character, whole-string, some kind of input reader) does not matter.

For example a bottom-up parser (Javascript, 284 characters):

```
function M(d){function c(a){throw"unexpected "+a;}function f(a){if("+"==a)return b.push(a),e;if(null==a)return b;c(a)}function e(a){if("n"==a)return b.push(a),b=[b],g;c(a)}function g(a){if("+"==a)return b.push(a),e;if(null==a)return b;c(a)}var b=[];if("n"==d)return b.push(d),f;c(d)};
```

When called:

```
 M('n')('+')('n')('+')('n')(null)
```

will return an array that in JSON-notation looks like this:

```
[["n", "+", "n"], "+", "n"]
```

---

Edit for the uninitiated in parsing: This is one of those questions where making a program produce the correct output is easy but the form of the program is essential for up-boats.

```
M -> M + n | n
```

Means that `M` consists of a previous `M`, a plus sign and a literal `"n"`. Or good `M` is a single `"n"` literal character.

There are several way of approaching this challenge, I'll describe my own solution, which is called bottom-up parsing. Character by character:

```
 Stack               Incoming Character         Action on stack
                     n                          
 n                   +                          reduce "n" to M
 M+                  n
 M+n                 +                          reduce "M + n" to M
 M+                  n                          
 M+n                 EOF                        reduce "M + n" to M
 M
```

The twist in this question is that the simplest form of parsers called "recursive-descent" parsers won't work because the grammar is left-recursive and that throws a recursive-descent parser into an infinite loop.

Comment: Would this question make more sense to me if I had ever taken any CS classes? ;-). Perhaps you can give a couple if input/output examples for the rest of us

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 51 bytes

```
f=->s{s.split(/(\+)(?=n$)/).map{|t|t['+n']?f[t]:t}}
```

This seems weirdly cumbersome. It can be called like `f['n+n+n']`.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <strike>13</strike> 15

If I have understood what did you mean by "the code to validate input is not necessary" correctly:

```
{'+/{[\"+"@]}*}
```

#### Example

```
{'+/{[\"+"@]}*}:T;
"n+n+n" T`
N
"n+n+n+n" T`
```

Output:

```
[["n" "+" "n"] "+" "n"]
[[["n" "+" "n"] "+" "n"] "+" "n"]
```

Or if I have to check the grammar:

## CJam, 24

```
{'+/_"n"a-L@{[\"+"@]}*?}
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? The Code only prints itself on http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Comment: @Falco I have changed the code to a function (or block) but forgot to change the "from stdin to stdout" line... Now added some examples.

Comment: What was wrong with the 13-char version? It seemed to work.

Comment: @MartinBüttner said it should be a function...

Answer (score 2):

## Augeas, 42

```
module A=let rec l=[key"n".(del"+""+".l)?]
```

Example usage, by adding:

```
test l get "n+n+n" = ?
```

and launching:

```
$ augparse a.aug
Test result: a.aug:2.0-.22:
{ "n"
  { "n"
    { "n" }
  }
}
```

Due to the bidirectional nature of Augeas lenses, the provided code also manages the reverse transformation, e.g. by using:

```
test l put "n" after clear "n/n/n" = ?
```

then launch augparse:

```
$ augparse a.aug
Test result: a.aug:2.0-.38:
"n+n+n"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> 13 bytes

```
L.U[b\+Z)cz\+
```

Took me forever to shorten it, but I did! I changed pretty much the entire algorithm. Defines a function `y` that takes one string argument.

[Live demo with 3-byte test harness and test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L.U%5Bb%5C%2BZ)cb%5C%2B%0Ayz&input=n%2Bn&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=n%0An%2Bn%0An%2Bn%2Bn&debug=1)

### Original

```
?tJu?qH\n+GH,GHzkJ]J
```

[Live demo and test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FtJu%3FqH%5Cn%2BGH%2CGHzkJ%5DJ&input=n&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=n%0An%2Bn%0An%2Bn%2Bn&debug=1)

Comment: For those (like me) that don't grok Pyth, how exactly does it create a function called y?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The `L` creates a function named `y` that takes an argument `b`. If you want, I'll add an explanation in a few. :)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I really want to learn one of these golfing languages.   I am just not competitive at all with the languages I am good at...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Just remember that algorithms beat languages. I've been beated by Python because the other person had a better method of solving the problem than I did. :)